# How to create nested dropdown in drodown item of navbar menu with bootstrap 3?

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested

friends!

Is there any opportunity to create nested dropdown(multilevel dropdown) inside of dropdown menu item with bootsrap 3? Here is http://jsfiddle.net/kkqxgfk6/1/ what i'm trying to do. May be I made mistake somewhere in the code, is that so?
Here is the html-code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> 
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li ><a href="#" >Something</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The nested "Dropdown2" menu item cann't be opened like its parent menu item called "Dropdown"

Comment: I shall be vastly obliged

Answer (score 1):

Add all bold content into your code.

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"  **onclick="event.stopPropagation();"**>
   <li class="dropdown" **id="test"**>
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" **id="test1"** data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Dropdown2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Add this code into javascript.

```
$( "#test1" ).click(function() {
        $(this).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $('#test').addClass("open");
    });
```

Reasons for your problem By default when you click inside dropdown it closes.
here we are adding classes dynamically to second dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

Create one more CSS file and define "Dropdown-submenu" class.
Apply this "Dropdown-submenu" class to your inner "LI" tag as:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"> 
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2 <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li ><a href="#" >Something</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

The CSS file Will define Dropdown-submenu as:

> ```
>    .dropdown-submenu {
> position:relative; } .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
> top:0;
> left:100%;
> margin-top:-6px;
> margin-left:-1px;
> -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
> -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
> border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px; } .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
> display:block; } .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
> display:block;
> content:" ";
> float:right;
> width:0;
> height:0;
> border-color:transparent;
> border-style:solid;
> border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
> border-left-color:#333333;
> margin-top:5px;
> margin-right:-10px; } .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
> border-left-color: #999999; } .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
> float:none; } .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
> left:-100%;
> margin-left:10px;
> -webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
> -moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;
> border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px; }
> ```